# How to use TabHost in CordovaActivity?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-tabhost

I have this sample cordova app, and I am trying to add TabHost to it. When I run it, it got crashed and the logcat says:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException:` Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{`io.cordova.hellocordova/io.cordova.hellocordova.MainActivity`}:
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException:` **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference**

Here is my Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Resources ressources = getResources();
        TabHost tabs = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();

        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, Utilitites.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabs
                .newTabSpec("Utilities")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete))
                .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, Locations.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabs
                .newTabSpec("Locations")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete))
                .setContent(intentApple);

        tabs.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabs.addTab(tabSpecApple);

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        // loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

It is because the class doesn't extend the `TabActivity`. If I do that, then I cannot run the `cordova activity` command `loadUrl(launchUrl)`.

Is there a way to use `TabHost` in `CordovaActivity`?

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) for a possible solution. `TabActivity` is deprecated depending on what API you are targeting. Further, it suggests using a `FragmentTabHost` which you can try putting into your layout and then continue to use `CordovaActivity`.

Comment: do you know how to migrate to gradle ? This cordova project doesnt have gradle.

Comment: You can find resources online to switch to using gradle but I don't see what switching to gradle has to do with your question anyways.

Comment: I am unable to import the FragmentActivity/FragmentTabHost. I thought migrating to gradle would allow me to import FragmentTabHost

Comment: Wow there have been way too many ways to add tabs in Android and it is confusing what is even recommended anymore. [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.html) says to use the action bar for tabs. Then when you look at [ActoinBar.Tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.Tab.html) it's deprecated. As far as I can tell you should now use a `TabLayout`. You can see an example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/).

Comment: Also, you cannot import those classes because you must not be including the android support library as a dependency in your project. You would need to add the support library as a dependency, similar to how you probably added cordova as a dependency.